# Getting Top 3 landing pages by month and channel in 1 API request

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is it possible to get the top 3 landing pages by channel and by month in one api request?  I can get all of the landing pages by channel and month, or I can get the top 3 landing pages for a certain month and channel.  But I'm not sure if this is possible in one call.

fwiw I'm using python

edit:
This returns all of the paths, but I would like for it to return only the top 3 for each month per channelGrouping.  I could do this in my code, but wanted to check if there was a way to do it through the api call first

```
  results = (service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date=start,
      end_date=end,
      dimensions='ga:landingPagePath,ga:nthMonth,ga:channelGrouping',
      sort='-nthMonth',
      metrics='ga:users').execute().get('rows', [])
```

Comment: what requests have you tried so far?  https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: I added a code snippet

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do this, so I just used Python's sort methods after grabbing all of the data